# Running non-ros python programs with rosrun

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I apologize if this isn't the right place for my question. I followed this guide  https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/26/face-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/ for face detection, and can run it using

```
python detect_faces_video.py --prototxt deploy.prototxt.txt \
    --model res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel
```

My goal now is to be able to run the `detect_faces_video.py` program using rosrun (I've included it at the end of this post). I will list the steps I have taken so far.

I began by creating a workspace named opencv_ros and a src, and in opencv_ros/src running catkin_create_pkg facescan rospy.

These are the files from the original folder I downloaded, and I copied these into `opencv_ros/src/facescan/src`, followed by running catkin_make at the base of the workspace:

```
sriram@sriram-ThinkPad-E580:~$ cd deep-learning-face-detection/
sriram@sriram-ThinkPad-E580:~/deep-learning-face-detection$ ls
deploy.prototxt.txt    iron_chic.jpg
detect_faces.py        res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel
detect_faces_video.py  rooster.jpg
```

In `opencv_ros/src/facescan/src`, I ran chmod +x for all the files in the folder, then added `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the top of the python program.

I then ran another `catkin_make`, along with `source ~/opencv_ros/devel/setup.bash`.

This shows my attempt to run the program using rosrun:

```
sriram@sriram-ThinkPad-E580:~/opencv_ros/src/facescan/src$ workon cv
(cv) sriram@sriram-ThinkPad-E580:~/opencv_ros/src/facescan/src$ rosrun facescan detect_faces_video.py --prototxt deploy.prototxt.txt --model res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel
from: can't read /var/mail/imutils.video
import-im6.q16: not authorized `np' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
import-im6.q16: not authorized `argparse' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
import-im6.q16: not authorized `imutils' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
import-im6.q16: not authorized `time' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
import-im6.q16: not authorized `cv2' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
/home/sriram/opencv_ros/src/facescan/src/detect_faces_video.py: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/sriram/opencv_ros/src/facescan/src/detect_faces_video.py: line 13: `ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()'
```

The imports are not authorized, and I feel like I need to change the rights to read | write for these imports, but I am not certain. I could also be completely wrong and need to be using cv_bridge for this. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with ROS Melodic and opencv 3.4. Any help would be greatly appreciated; I tried learning about rosrun from textbooks, but was not able to find the appropriate solution.

Main script code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# USAGE
# python detect_faces_video.py --prototxt deploy.prototxt.txt --model res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel

# import the necessary packages
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load our serialized model from disk
print("[INFO] loading model...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])

# initialize the video stream and allow the cammera sensor to warmup
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
time.sleep(2.0)

# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
    # grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
    # to have a maximum width of 400 pixels
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
 
    # grab the frame dimensions and convert it to a blob
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300)), 1.0,
        (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
 
    # pass the blob through the network and obtain the detections and
    # predictions
    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()

    # loop over the detections
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the
        # prediction
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
        # greater than the minimum confidence
        if confidence < args["confidence"]:
            continue

        # compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for the
        # object
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
 
        # draw the bounding box of the face along with the associated
        # probability
        text = "{:.2f}%".format(confidence * 100)
        y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
            (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame, text, (startX, y),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # show the output frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
 
    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# do a bit of cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331386/running-non-ros-python-programs-with-rosrun/) by [avi8or](https://answers.ros.org/users/44379/avi8or/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a good chance that your `detect_faces_video.py` doesn't have a [shebang line](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines). That would make it work when started directly with `python ..`, but `rosrun` doesn't start a node/script like that.

Verify the first line of `detect_faces_video.py` is something like `#!/usr/bin/env python`. If there isn't such a line, that would most likely be your problem.

> The imports are not authorized, and I feel like I need to change the rights to read | write for these imports

that has most likely nothing to do with it. Your shell is just using the wrong program to interprete the Python script, leading to all sorts of problems when that interpreter is trying to make sense of your Python statements.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avi8or](https://answers.ros.org/users/44379/avi8or/) on 2019-08-24**:
Thank you! I added `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the `detect_faces_video.py` file in the original download folder, not my workspace. I am now able to run with rosrun.